# Website on CSS doesn't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My website is working perfect on Safari, Opera, Firefox and Chrome but when I run it on IE it doesn't work correctly.

Link to the website is [here](http://mapy-polplan.pl/nowa/mapy.php?mapa=cieszyn).

I need to have a map on the center of the screen, but on IE it is under the left menu, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a different style sheet for ie

```
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

It may be something to do with the way padding in rendered in webkit browsers.

Hope that helps

Comment: Try adding a float to the map

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found to add styles for certain browsers is to use this in your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
```

This will add a class onto the html tag for each browser. You can then style for certain browsers like so:

```
#wrapper { width:300px; }
.ie7 #wrapper { width:400px; } /*Specific to IE7*/
```

No browser specific style-sheets needed!

Comment: But i dont know what is wrong. 
I dont know what part of CSS is not working correct on IE